WebSocket connection Disconnects When Browser Tab is Inactive
I'm using Spring WebSocket with STOMP to establish a WebSocket connection between my server and clients, which are using stomp.js on the frontend. My application works well when the tab is active, but if the browser tab becomes inactive (for instance, if the user switches tabs or minimizes the browser), the WebSocket connection disconnects after a certain period. This disconnection seems to be a built-in feature in many modern browsers.
To keep the connection alive, I’ve enabled a heartbeat mechanism in my Spring WebSocket configuration. My server is configured to send and receive periodic heartbeats to/from the client, but this approach hasn’t been effective in preventing the connection from closing when the tab is inactive.
I've researched this issue extensively and understand that browser-based WebSocket disconnections can be challenging to prevent when the tab is inactive. However, I couldn’t find a concrete solution that works reliably across different browsers. Here is my current WebSocket configuration on the server:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@ConditionalOnExpression("${enable-websocket:false}")
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Value("${websocket.simple-broker.destinations}")
    private String[] simpleBrokerDestinations;

    @Value("${websocket.application-destination.prefixes}")
    private String applicationDestinationPrefixes;

    @Value("${websocket.endpoint}")
    private String websocketEndpoint;

    @Value("${websocket.allowed-origin-patterns}")
    private String[] allowedOriginPatterns;

    @Value("${websocket.server.heartbeat:30000}")
    private Long serverHeartbeat;

    @Value("${websocket.client.heartbeat:30000}")
    private Long clientHeartbeat;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler websocketHeartbeatTaskScheduler = websocketHeartbeatTaskScheduler();
        registry.enableSimpleBroker(simpleBrokerDestinations)
                .setHeartbeatValue(new long[]{serverHeartbeat, clientHeartbeat})
                .setTaskScheduler(websocketHeartbeatTaskScheduler);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint(websocketEndpoint)
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns(allowedOriginPatterns)
                .addInterceptors();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler websocketHeartbeatTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
        scheduler.initialize();
        return scheduler;
    }
}

My Question: Are there any workarounds or configurations in Spring WebSocket that can reliably prevent the disconnection when the tab is inactive? Would implementing custom periodic pings from the client help keep the connection alive, even if the heartbeat mechanism doesn't? If so, how could this be achieved with stomp.js?
Are there any alternative approaches to handle re-establishing the connection and resyncing missed messages when the tab is reactivated, in case avoiding disconnection is not possible? I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions from others who may have faced a similar challenge.

It should not be a problem for you you just have to autoReconnect when user back if you're using a js client (like this one @stomp/stompjs
) this should be done automatically
By the way i d'ont think the browser close the connection is just the js client that stop to send the heartbeat if the tab is not focused then the browser can freeze some part try to just send the hearbeat from the server only and it should disconnect you

more information could be found here => https://github.com/stomp-js/stompjs/pull/579#issuecomment-2515497976

i faced a similar problem. In my setup the message broker is Rabbit MQ (not the simple one). To keep alive connection even if tab browser is inactive i set up client incoming heartbeat to 0 (disabled). The server knows that client will not send heart beat.
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket)
stompClient.heartbeat.outgoing = 0
stompClient.heartbeat.incoming = 30000

Source https://stomp-js.github.io/stomp-websocket/codo/extra/docs-src/Usage.md.html
My websocket configuration:
public class WebSocketSTOMPConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

private final InboundInterceptor channelInboundInterceptor;
private final OutboundInterceptor channelOutboundInterceptor;
private final WebsocketHandshakeInterceptor websocketHandshakeInterceptor;

@Value("${base.url}")
private String endpoint;
@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host:localhost}")
private String relayHost;
@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port:5672}")
private Integer relayPort;
@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username:guest}")
private String login;
@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password:guest}")
private String passCode;


public WebSocketSTOMPConfig(InboundInterceptor channelInboundInterceptor, OutboundInterceptor channelOutboundInterceptor, WebsocketHandshakeInterceptor websocketHandshakeInterceptor) {
    this.channelInboundInterceptor = channelInboundInterceptor;
    this.channelOutboundInterceptor = channelOutboundInterceptor;
    this.websocketHandshakeInterceptor = websocketHandshakeInterceptor;
}


@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
    LOGGER.info("New stomp endpoint exposed at: {}", endpoint);
    stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint(endpoint.concat("/stomp"))
            .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
            .addInterceptors(websocketHandshakeInterceptor)
            .withSockJS()
            .setSuppressCors(true); //avoid duplicate response headers
}

/**
 * Topics – common conversations or chat topics open to any client or user. In a multi-application server scenarios
 * this allows each server's user registry to be aware of users connected to other servers.
 * <p>
 * Queues – reserved for specific users and their current sessions
 * <p>
 * Endpoints – generic endpoints
 * <p>
 * STOMP messages whose destination header begins with /app are routed to @MessageMapping methods in @Controller classes.
 **/
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    // rabbit MQ STOMP broker
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic")
            .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/registry.broadcast")
            .setRelayHost(relayHost)
            .setRelayPort(relayPort)
            .setClientLogin(login)
            .setSystemLogin(login)
            .setClientPasscode(passCode)
            .setSystemPasscode(passCode);
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/users");
}


@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(channelInboundInterceptor);
}

@Override
public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(channelOutboundInterceptor);
}

